# Is Authx really alpha?

Tags: core, formbuilder

On the status page I get "To generate authenticated email links for custom forms, enable extended authentication services (AuthX) in Manage Extensions." Ok, but the AuthX description says that it is Alpha stage and "This is a new, undeveloped module." All the links just say http://FIXME. So what's the deal? I'm not excited about adding untested code to my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: It's now marked as stable :)

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23601

Answer (score 0):

There's a larger topic about who in the civi universe is responsible for testing and QA, but the short answer is yes it's alpha right now, but the reason you're seeing that message on the status page is because the "form core" extension is installed.